# How to differentiate empty string and nothing in a map

Tags: go

The following code yields `true`. So I'm wondering for `map[string]string` in Golang, is there a way to differentiate empty string and nothing?

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    m := make(map[string]string)
    m["abc"] = ""
    fmt.Println(m["a"] == m["abc"]) //true
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If by "nothing" you mean that the element is not in the map you can use the  `ok` idiom:

```
val, ok := myMap["value"] // ok is true if value was in the map
```

You can find more information in [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#maps).